# Simplify this expression

Tags: c++, c, expression

Let `a`, `b` be positive integers with different values. Is there any way to simplify these expressions:

```
bool foo(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    if (a % 2 == 0)
      return (b % 2) ^ (a < b); // Should I write "!=" instead of "^" ?
    else      
      return ! ( (b % 2) ^ (a < b) ); // Should I write "(b % 2) == (a < b)"? 
}
```

I am interpreting the returned value as a boolean.

Comment: You should include a plain english explanation of what you're trying to do here...

Comment: It is a little bit difficult because it is part of a complex algorithm.

Comment: I'm sure, but we need to know what inputs should cause what in return.

Comment: Are you trying to return a boolean value or a string of some sort?

Comment: The problem is that without knowing what your complex algorithm is trying to achieve it's hard for us to help. Is there a particular goal you are trying to achieve? And *please* don't say "optimize my code"

Comment: I want to return a boolean value.

Comment: You need to decide what the spec. is for this piece of code. For example, you could simplify it to `return 0;` but perhaps that wouldn't meet your requirements.

Comment: `return ( a % 2 ) ^ ( b % 2) ^ ( a < b )` maybe?  I'm not 100% sure what's going on here.

Comment: If you want to return a boolean value it may be helpful to note that '^' is a bitwise XOR operator. Also note that C++ doesn't have a logical XOR.

Comment: When you say simplify, do you mean "make it easier for a human to understand", or "make the computer run it in fewer instructions"? Keep in mind that the two may be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Kevin, I'm talking about make the computer run it in fewer instructions. Sorry

Comment: As usual, leave optimization to the compiler. I also don't see what you are trying to make more efficient: the bottleneck, if any, in this code will be the % operator, division will most likely be a far worse culprint than limited branch prediction. You would then manually optimize it into `if (a & 1u)`. But don't do this unless you are absolutely sure it is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How is it different from

```
 (a%2)^(b%2)^(a<b)
```

which in turn is

```
 ((a^b)&1)^(a<b)
```

or, indeed

```
 ((a ^ b) & 1) != (a < b)
```

**Edited to add:** Thinking about it some more, this is just the xor of the first and last bits of `(a-b)` (if you use 2's complement), so there is probably a machine-specific ASM sequence which is faster, involving a rotate instruction.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, don't mix operators of different operator families. You are mixing relational/boolean operators with bitwise operators, and regular arithmetic.

This is what I *think* you are trying to do, I'm not sure, since I don't understand the purpose of your code: it is neither readable nor self-explaining.

```
bool result;
bool a_is_even = (a % 2) == 0;
bool b_is_even = (b % 2) == 0;

if (a_is_even == b_is_even) // both even or both odd
  result = a < b;
else
  result = a >= b;

return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning a truth value, a boolean, then your proposed changes do not change the semantics of the code. That's because bitwise XOR, when used in a truth context, is the same as `!=`.

In my view your proposed changes make the code much easier to understand. Quite why the author thought bitwise XOR would be appropriate eludes me. I guess some people think that sort of coding is clever. I don't.

If you want to know the relative performance of the two versions, write a program and time the difference. I'd be surprised if you could measure any difference between them. And I'd be equally surprised if these lines of code were your performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

I program in C# but I'd think about something like this:

return (a % 2 == 0) && ((b % 2) ^ (a < b))

Considering from you comments that '^' is equivalent to '=='

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not much information around this issue, try this:

```
int temp = (b % 2) ^ (a < b);
if (a % 2 == 0)
  return temp;
else      
  return !temp;
```

This should be less code if the compiler hasn't optimized it already.